# JDBC Cache statement per connection

Tags: jdbc, prepared-statement, connection-pooling

i know when using preparestatement the statement will be cache for the next time use , but i've read the docs which said the Cache is made per connection , from my understanding this means that each connection maintain it's own Cache . i.e. Connection A can't use the statement cached in Connection B even those two connections are in the same connection pool .

---

i'm wondering why can't the connection pool manage the Cache for all connections in it , so the statement could be reused by all connections.

my question : am i right about this ? or i just misunderstand this. and if i'm right , how about my wondering mentioned above . can it be implemented that way ?

Comment: The Connection Pool has little to do with it. The remote database (if cachable statements are supported and enabled) will maintain a statement that has already been query plan'd.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch connection pools can also implement a statement cache (eg store a number of prepared statements, even if the logical statement handle was closed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A statement handle is - usually - linked to the physical connection that created it (not only at the JDBC side, but also at the database side). It is also deleted/closed/disposed when the connection is closed. As it is linked to the connection, the handle can't be used from a different connection, therefor the statement cache - if any - is per connection.

Even if this were technically possible, there could be additional problems (eg privilege leaks if connection have different rights, etc).

Comment: i don't think privilege is a problem , why the cache statement will have  relation to the user privilege ? when was the user's privilege being check ? tks for ur answer :D

Comment: @JasonHuang Lets assume the hypothetical case that statement handles can be shared across connections, now assume that a connection with a different user gains access to a handle for an object it doesn't have rights to. The mere knowledge of the existence of certain objects could be a privilege leak. Or - for the sake of argument - the database only checks rights at prepare time: having a handle prepared by a connection with broad rights would leak that privilege to a connection with insufficient rights.

Comment: tks for ur reply , commonly we only set one user info in db property in  application's connection pool,so maybe the user privilege problem won't happen . because when the properties being changed , the connection pool would be reinitilized and previouse cached statements will be refreshed .

Comment: That is all academic, as statement handles are only per connection.